# MySQL dump import into MariaDB syntax error to use near '*/'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, syntax

This is the result from mysqldump 10.13 and MySQL 8.0.28 Server.

```
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user name',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='User table';

DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`admin`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `user_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO user_language(user_id, language_id) VALUES (1,1); */;;
```

If I try to import this piece with `mysql <db> < dump.sql` into a MariaDB 10.6.7, it results into `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 9: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1`

I would appreciate any info on why this is happening and how to avoid it.

Comment: File a bug report with MariaDB.com.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `BEGIN ... END` solves the issue.

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`admin`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `user_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_language(user_id, language_id) VALUES (1,1);
END */;;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are significant differences in the `mysql` and `information_schema` databases between 8.0 and MariaDB.  Avoid trying to move any data either direction.  (Ditto for `performance_schema`.)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to import a MySQL dump to MariaDB?

Comment: @Aley - If you already have the extra databases in the dump file, the best I can suggest is to edit the file to get rid of loading them.  (Maybe someone else has a better idea.)

Answer (score 0):

The dump formats are not completely compatible.

This particular issue is explained in "MariaDB Server Documentation » SQL Statements & Structure » SQL Statements » [Comment Syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/)":

> The following executable statement will not work due to the delimiter inside the executable portion:
>
> `/*M!100100 select 1 ; */`
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
>
> Instead, the delimiter should be placed outside the executable portion:
>
> `/*M!100100 select 1 */;`
>
> ```
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> ```

Comment: The snippet from the question is just an excerpt. The actual dump is huge and contains a lot more triggers. Do you know a way how to make the dump compatible with MariaDB?

Comment: Also the interesting part is that the error points to line 9, which is the forelast line and it does not contain any semicolons.

Comment: @Aley *the error points to line 9, which is the forelast line and it does not contain any semicolons* Empty lines are not counted, maybe? *Do you know a way how to make the dump compatible with MariaDB?* Try to use mariadb-dump (really - mysqldump) taken from MariaDB installation.

Comment: Empty lines count. I tested it with another empty line. It shows line 10 now.

Comment: Exporting it with mariadb-dump shows the same error on reimport.

Comment: @Aley If so then the only recommendation is in editing this dump manually.

Comment: Seems like `BEGIN ... END` solves the issue.